# Помогите найти ошибку С++

Tags: c++

При вводе a=3.14 и выше вылетает ошибка. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#define pi 3.14
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float g, a;

    cout << "Enter a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << a << endl;

    if (a>pi) {
        g=(1.0/3)*pow(a,2)-pow(a-pi*pi, 1.0/3);
    }
    else if (a==pi) {
        g=pow(log(a+ (pi/3)+1), 3) + exp(a+pi);
    }
    else {
        g=tan((a*pi)/6)-pow(sin((a*pi)/2),2);
    } 
    cout << "g= " << g;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

Но при `3.14 < a <= 9.8596` (попадаем в первое условие) выражение `pow(a - pi * pi, 1.0 / 3)` будет выдавать ошибку, причина описана в сообщении от @helldrg.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#define pi 3.14f  //  f - для типа float, чтобы сравнение было верным 
                  //  (проблема точности нецелых чисел)

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float g, a;

    cout << "Enter a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << a << endl;

    if ( a > pi ) 
    {
        g = (1.0 / 3) * pow(a, 2) - pow(a - pi * pi, 1.0 / 3);
    }
    else if ( a == pi ) 
    {
        g = pow(log(a + (pi / 3) + 1), 3) + exp(a + pi);
    }
    else 
    {
        g = tan( (a * pi) / 6 ) - pow( sin( (a * pi) / 2 ), 2 );
    } 

    cout << "g = " << g;

    return 0;
}
```

Пример:

```
float a;
double b;

a = 3.14;
b = 3.14;

cout << (3.14 == 3.14) << '\n';   //  True
cout << (3.14 == 3.14d) << '\n';  //  True 
cout << (a == 3.14) << '\n';      //  False
cout << (a == 3.14f) << '\n';     //  True
cout << (b == 3.14) << '\n';      //  True
cout << (b == 3.14f) << '\n';     //  False
```

Можно сделать вывод, что просто запись нецелого числа по дефолту имеет тип `double`.

Comment: *Можно сделать вывод, что просто запись нецелого числа по дефолту имеет тип double.* - достаточно просто прочитать стандарт или учебник.

Comment: @Harry Ну я, например, вообще на C++ не пишу, и соотв. стандартов не знаю, учебников не читал.  Но пару раз запустив в онлайн компиляторе и проанализировав код догадался в чём может крыться ошибка, протестил - так и оказалось.  Потому и поделился своими выводами в ответе и привёл пример для понимания, чтобы ТС понял корень проблемы, а не просто взял готовое решение.

Comment: Спасибо, понял в чем проблема. Помогло использование функции cbrt вместо pow(x, 1/3)

Answer (score 1):

pow(x, y) eсли число x отрицательное, а степень y не является целой, функция печатает сообщение об ошибке. Эта ошибка появляется когда в результате математической операции получается значение, которое слишком велико по величине.

Comment: Но тут проблема в другом, дело в том, что когда `a = 3.14` условие в коде `a > pi == true` (компилятор gcc).  А вот уже там происходит ошибка функции `pow`.  Но источник проблемы в другом.